# How to write tuples into columns (a table) separated by tab \t in a new text file using only python's built-in functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python and currently creating a program that accepts a text file containing values to be computed and produces a new text file that contains the output.

I am currently trying to format tuples into columns — like a table but only using python's built-in functions. However, when I try to run my code, it only shows the last row of information.

**Here is what I am trying to work with:**

```
def writeArea (dict_float, area):
    '''
    This function re-writes the information stored in the dictionary
    into a new text file with filename: Area.txt with info being
    separated by tab (\t). Accepts dictionary and area. Returns none.
    '''
    with open('Area.txt', 'w') as f:

        tuple_coord=tuple(dict_float.values()) #converts dictionary values to tuple
        northing, easting = zip(*tuple_coord)#splits tuple into separate values for N and E
    
        header="Point \t Northing \t Easting \n" #string for header
        point=tuple(dict_float.keys()) #creates tuple out of dictionary keys
    
        i=0
        txt=("{} \t {:.3f} \t {:.3f}")
        while i<len(point):
            table=(txt.format(i+1,float(northing[i]),float(easting[I])))
            i=i+1 #formats into columns with numerical values limited to 3 decimal places

        finalarea = ("\n\nThe area computed is {:.3f} square units").format(area)
        #prints out the area computation

        f.write(header)
        f.write(table)
        f.write(finalarea)
```

**When running this code, this is the text file output:**

```
Point    Northing    Easting
5    19969.272   20007.765

The area computed is 1314.469 square units
```

**This is the output that I am expecting:**

```
Point    Northing    Easting
1    20000.000   20000.000
2    20026.575   20030.782
3    19995.354   20026.848
4    19992.802   20062.690
5    19969.272   20007.765

The area computed is 1314.469 square units
```

Comment: try using append mode 'a' instead of write mode 'w'

Comment: No, the problem is your loop is overwriting the `table` variable each time.  When the loop ends, all you are left with is the final one.  Instead of saving `table`, just do the `f.write` inside the loop.  Write the header before you enter the loop.